# authenticationrequired error when trying to pull docker images with Docker CLI

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine, boot2docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to pull a simple hello-world image from docker hub using :

```
docker run hello-world
```

But I'm getting this error on Windows 7 :

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: authenticationrequired.
```

I've tried so many different things but none seem to work :

1 - I tried logging in, but I'm getting the same error :

`docker login`

Tried my username, my email ... Same error :

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: authenticationrequired
```

2 - Restarted docker machine, same error.

3 - Reinstalling Docker and Oracle VirtualBox multiple times

4 - Done all the steps here : https://github.com/docker/kitematic/wiki/Common-Proxy-Issues-&-Fixes

I really don't know how to fix this anymore.

Comment: can you try to create a login at docker hub and then use those credentials https://hub.docker.com/

Comment: I did exactly that. I'm able to log in hub.docker.com but not through the CLI.

Comment: Try Kitematic...

Comment: I get this when I'm using Kitematic : `tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 84 84:80`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I tried to login to the docker behind a corporate proxy.  Are you in a similar situation? If so, see if you add "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/" to the exemption list for proxy's HTTPS analysis.

If you are not behind a proxy, check to see if you have any software that do a HTTPS analysis.  Sometimes software like Fiddler or Antivirus does that.  If you found anything like that see if you can whitelist the url

Hope it helps.  I had a hard time figuring this out for my issue